# как затенить блок при наведении и показать какой то текст по центру внутри блока ?Спасибо!

Tags: html, css

нужно чтобы поверх блока circle это круглая картинка при наведении чтобы она затемнилась и появилась надпись MORE

```html
<div style="background:url(#);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover" class="circle">
</div>
```

Comment: В чем у вас проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вам пример

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle:hover .circle__mask{
  display: block;
}

.circle__mask {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="circle__mask">More</div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, а как сделать чтобы затемнение копировало круг а не вылазило т.е сейчас подсвечивается квадратный блок ?

Comment: http://www.picshare.ru/view/10260330/ вот как при таком коде подсвечивается и как выровнять этот море по вертикали?

Comment: @wantstudy Либо так же его скруглить, либо родительскому блоку overflow: hidden; В моем примере квадратный блок не видно